# GRAV CMS -- Featherlight.js won't work with Cardstack theme

Tags: plugins, themes, featherlight.js, grav

So apparently [Cardstack](https://github.com/khanduras/grav-theme-cardstack) theme for Grav has a conflict with Featherlight.js lightbox plugin. With the default Antimatter theme the plugin works fine, but with Cardstack there seems to be no way to get it working.

I installed the plugin via GPM as usual, then copied the `featherlight.yaml` file from `user/plugins/featherlight/featherlight.yaml` into `user/config/plugins/featherlight.yaml` and set `active: true`.

I then provided the markdown with `![image](image.jpg?lightbox=1024,800&resize=200,200)` but nothing happens when you click the image.

We're able to use UI kit's lightbox (Cardstack is built on UIkit) with HTML. For example:
`<a href="/user/pages/02.cards/test/01.test/mountains.jpg" data-uk-lightbox title="Mountains">` works, but we need a solution using Markdown. This is because, we're building a site where users post an image with a Markdown file with their name and other information. Asking users to write a lengthy HTML-link would be too demanding and prone to spelling errors.

I already posted about this on the [Grav forum](https://getgrav.org/forum#!/plugin-development:featherlight-wont-work) and it got one reply telling to open a issue on the Cardstack theme's github, which I did, but I haven't gotten any replies and the guy who built the theme hasn't been active for almost a month.

Comment: Any errors in the console?